# How can you detect intersection between any two quadrilaterals in 2D?

Tags: quadrilateral, collision-detection

What is the easiest way to detect an intersection between **any** two quadrilaterals? I want to know this because I'm creating a game with quadrilateral tiles, and to see if they collide, then you can place down a new quadrilateral.

I'm pretty sure there's a simple formula, but I'm not sure what it is, and after browsing through a lot of StackExchange sites, I found nothing to do with quadrilateral collisions; just simpler circle and rectangles collisions. I'm not sure, but a polygon-polygon collision isn't going to be my first pick for the formula, but if it's the only one, then that's fine.

To sum up, I really just need to know whether there is a quick formula to detect if any two quadrilaterals are colliding. I just need to have a *true* or *false*, and not anything more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the quadrilaterals convex?

Comment: I intend it to be a convex quadrilateral. I think it would be nice if the formula could include both non-convex and convex, but if that makes it much more difficult to do non-convex, I'd rather just do convex.